# DKIM Only works on Short Messages

Tags: php, dkim, postfix-mta

**The Problem:**

I am using OpenDKIM with Postfix. The mail is generated in PHP using the following code and then sent with `mail()`:

```
// message
$message  = "--$hash".PHP_EOL;
$message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".PHP_EOL;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
$message .= base64_encode($body).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
$message .= "--$hash".PHP_EOL;
```

OpenDKIM works fine for any messages that are under 742 characters in length, but if the message is 742 characters or more, Google reports that the DKIM "`body hash did not verify`".

Looking at DKIM and Google, I can't find any information on what would cause this. I have tried multiple messages that are 741 characters (all pass) and multiple that are 742 characters (all fail).

---

**Errors:**

The only error is in Google's receipt of the email (which it says it can't authenticate):

```
dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify) header.i=@mailer.example.com;
```

`/var/log/maillog` has the following (or something similar) on successful and unsuccessful emails:

```
Nov  5 00:58:57 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX opendkim[3953]: 7D2946081A: DKIM-Signature field added (s=default, d=mailer.example.com)
```

---

**Solution:**

As per @Adrien Lebner's solution below, it was a simple change from

```
base64_encode($body)
```

to

```
chunk_split(base64_encode($body), 76, PHP_EOL)
```

that fixed the issue.

Comment: Any error message ?

Comment: Can you add the content of `mail._domainkey` TXT DNS zone ? (edit your answer with additional info will be cleaner)

Comment: @AdrienLeber Added and organized.

Comment: Can post the full mail too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you send the same content on mutiple lines ?

DKIM may break if line length is too long :

> 2.1.1.  Line Length Limits
>
> There are two limits that this specification places on the number
>   of    characters in a line.  Each line of characters MUST be no more
>   than    998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters,
>   excluding    the CRLF.

Comment: This is almost definitely it. The emails are being encoded in base64 and are therefore sent as one line. Thanks!